# how to get subAggregation in elasticsearch by using java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a aggregation,

```
MetricsAggregationBuilder aggregation =
            AggregationBuilders
                    .cardinality("agg")
                    .field("age");
```

and I have another aggregation that contain 'agg'

```
FilterAggregationBuilder filterAggregationBuilder = AggregationBuilders.filter("agf");
    filterAggregationBuilder.filter(FilterBuilders.termFilter("age", 20));
    filterAggregationBuilder.subAggregation(aggregation);
```

I can get agf aggregation by using

```
Cardinality agg2 = searchResponse.getAggregations().get("agf");
```

but how can I get aggregation 'agg' and 'agg''s values